# Running Webservice on Ubuntu with mono/xps

Tags: monodevelop, ubuntu-11.10

I've installed an Ubuntu 11.10 on aws.amazon.com for tyhe purpose of running a webservice on it. I have tested the webservice using XPS on my Windows 7 Machine now I want to deploy it on the Ubuntu box. I think I have xsp4 set up. i went to the asp.net-demos folder and ran the comand "xsp4" and it started xspL:

Listening on address: 0.0.0.0
Root directory: /usr/share/asp.net-demos
Listening on port: 8080 (non-secure)
Hit Return to stop the server.

How do I now connect to it through the internet? do I have to setup the port to be exposed?

Comment: Are you asking how to do port forwarding on linux?

Comment: I'm asking how do I expose the web service to the internet, using the xsp4 command

Answer (score 0):

I realized the issue was with aws.amzon.com I had to configure the allowed ip addresses.